# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: new near line 1

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I just got following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: new near line 1, column 81 [select new com.test.user.request.api.entity.UserRequestEntity(new com.test.user.request.api.entity.UserViewEntity(generatedAlias0.user.email, new com.test.user.request.api.entity.ContactViewEntity_(generatedAlias0.user.contact.firstName, generatedAlias0.user.contact.lastName))) from com.test.user.request.api.entity.UserRequestEntity as generatedAlias0 where ( upper(generatedAlias0.user.contact.lastName) like upper(:param0) ) and ( generatedAlias0.organization.id=:param1 )]
```

I'm coding a query using JPA criteria API which looks as following

```
final CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = this.em.getCriteriaBuilder();

final CriteriaQuery<UserRequestEntity> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(UserRequestEntity.class);
final Root<UserRequestEntity> userRequest = this.createUserRequestRoot(query, true);

Path<UserViewEntity> user = userRequest.get(UserRequestEntity_.user);
Path<ContactViewEntity> contact = user.get(UserViewEntity_.contact);
CompoundSelection<ContactViewEntity_> contactSelection = criteriaBuilder.construct(ContactViewEntity_.class, contact.get(ContactViewEntity_.firstName), contact.get(ContactViewEntity_.lastName));
CompoundSelection<UserViewEntity> userSelection = criteriaBuilder.construct(UserViewEntity.class, user.get(UserViewEntity_.email), contactSelection);
CompoundSelection<UserRequestEntity> userRequestSelection = criteriaBuilder.construct(UserRequestEntity.class, userSelection);

query.select(userRequestSelection);
```

For the overview I need 9-10 fields coming from multiple entities. If I get then in a multiselection I need a constructor with 9-10 parameters. I thought I can solve it using compound selection.

I know there are another way to initialize assotiated data by using fetch join, but the problem I have with fetch join is that I have a generic filter converter converting filters from the UI to the criteria api predicates and if there are filters for the assotiated entitiy (userRequest.user.contact.firstName) the converter creates duplicated joins, because it seems the join instance won't be reused.

Is there any way to make compound selection work?